Can a combinator basis set of size two have an arbitrary combinator?
The S and K combinators are a known basis set of combinators. Such a set is called universal. However, two combinators being universal is the limit on universality, as a single combinator cannot be universal.
This brings an interesting question on how far we can go. Given any combinator X, does there exist a combinator X$^\prime$ such that X and X$^\prime$ are universal? It is important to clarify that X and X$^\prime$ are proper, because a single improper combinator can be universal.

Is there such an $X'$ for $X=I$?

@EmilJeřábek I actually considered that case before this more general one, but I was unable to prove it either way.

@EmilJeřábek I think I found one. Let $X = I$. Then $X^\prime = \lambda a b c d e. b c (b e d)$. However, I have no proof that $X$ and $X^\prime$ are universal.
